# Configure Record Center

Tags: records-center

i have team site in share point2010 and i create record center site,then i configure record center site in 
central administration>General Application Settings>Configure Send To Connections

for send document form team site to record center site

all document move to drop off library in record center, i want  documents of one library send to specific library in record center or document of word type send to specific library in record center.

how can do this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Fatima,

The term you are looking for is "Content Organizer Rule", in your Records Center site... In Site Settings -> Site Actions -> Manage Site Features -> **Make sure Content Organizer feature is Active!**

After that, Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Content Organizer Rules -> Here you can define a rule to route the document accordingly!

If no rules are matched the document goes to Drop Off Library, which is happening in your case... Once you define the rules, the documents will be routed accordingly...

Following should be helpful:
[Creating a Content Organizer Rule in SharePoint 2010](http://sharepointrecordsmanagement.com/2012/07/10/creating-a-content-organizer-rule-in-sharepoint-2010/)
[Create Content Organizer Rules to route documents](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/create-content-organizer-rules-to-route-documents-HA101807927.aspx)
[Content Organizer for a Document Library](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2010/11/03/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-content-organizer-for-document-library.aspx)